# Duas for helping one from stammering issue

Tags: dua

I am having this stammering problem since from childhood. At school I have been embarrassed many times because of my stammering issue.I went to speech therapist but doctor says there is no complete cure only some breathing exercise which has been not so effective on me.

So if there is any dua which our prophet Muhammad said for helping one from speech problem.
If there is any dua for this,please answer

Comment: There's one healing which would even have benefits for your afterlife. Search for a scholar who has a connected chain to our Prophet () in Quran and learn Quran recitation with tajweed. Beside this you can consult a therapist. But most people I know who used to stutter either could get rid of it by singing or tajweed as both would be a good training for the respiratory muscle and at least while reciting Quran or singing you wouldn't have this issue and maybe you'll get totally rid of it!

Comment: You're more likely to successfully deal with a stammer by consulting a speech therapist.

Answer (score 4):

```
رَبِّ اشْرَحْ لِي صَدْرِي وَيَسِّرْ لِي أَمْرِي وَاحْلُلْ عُقْدَةً مِنْ لِسَانِي يَفْقَهُوا قَوْلِي
```

Rabb-ishrah li sadri, wa yassir li ‘amri, Wah-lul ‘uqdatam-min-li-saani, Yaf-qahuu qawlii

O my Lord! Open for me my chest (grant me self-confidence, contentment, and boldness); Ease my task for me; And remove the impediment from my speech, so they may understand what I say
[Surah Ta-Ha; 20:25-28]

A du’a that Musa (alayhis salam) made when proceeding to the court of Fir’awn (Pharoah) for the arguments (inviting him to Islam)

Source:https://dailyduaa.com/category/dua-for-work-studies/

This dua my grand father taught me in my child hood, Insha-Allah it will cure your problem, and yes don't forget to recite Durood Shareef before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Salams bro, I have the same issue , Dua is correct , also MashaAllah it’s is not a life problem, it’s because of anxiety. No other explanation, I’m sure when you are alone you never get stammers , same with all of us who have stammers, get some anxiety pills from a psychiatrist bro. May Allah cure us all Ameen.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, and i think slow speed can overcome stammering and along with that reading Dua which is "رَبِّ اشْرَحْ لِي صَدْرِي وَيَسِّرْ لِي أَمْرِي وَاحْلُلْ عُقْدَةً مِنْ لِسَانِي يَفْقَهُوا قَوْلِي" this will help you reduce your stammering.